# WriteResult mongoDB for update operation

Tags: mongodb, updates

I want to insert records and updating attributes using update and get the status of the update. I used getN () method WriteResult. The problem is that if the attributes exist it always returns me one while I wish that I returns 0. thank you

here is my update request :

```
db.friends.update( {adv: "man2ist", "list.id" : {$ne : "5" }} , {$addToSet : {"list" : {'id' : "5" , 'value' : 100 }} } ,false , true);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `n` value in a `WriteResult` provides the number of documents that were updated, and it can only be 0 if your update query didn't match any documents and you're not doing an upsert. Your best bet here might be to use [`findAndModify`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5.3/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndModify%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29) and make a comparison to the old document.